# mysql distinct to form selections

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a form that takes the select options from mySQL database so that all different values in one column are listed. The code that is not working is following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="startlist.php">
<select id="selectbasic" name="klass" class="form-control">
<?PHP
$connection = mysqli_connect("link","dbuser","pass","dbname");
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Klass FROM Voistlejad";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connection,$result)) {
echo $row["Klass"];
echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
    <option value='32KK5B'>32KK5B</option><!--This is how it needs to be-->
</select>
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Move on</button>
</form>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: "not working" is a very imprecise description of the behavior you observe. There could be all kinds of things wrong. Here's some tips: enable php error reporting.  test the return from mysqli_connect, and if its FALSE, get the error using mysql_connect_error.  after calling mysqli_query, test if $results is FALSE, get the error using mysqli_error.   There's very little evidence of any debugging. StackOverflow is a question answer site, not a debugging service. "Something is wrong with my code" is *not* a question.

Comment: Start breaking it down, Take pieces out starting from the TOP, and find what line fails. Then google that issue specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up where to use single and double quotes..
Generally, for arrays/objects like $row, you get the value from the array with either no quotes, or single quotes,  echo $row['Klass']

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connection,$result)) {

echo $row['Klass']; // single quotes

echo "<option value='". $row['Klass'] ."'>". $row['Klass'] ."</option>";
 } 
// shows sql error ONLY if there is one to show
 printf(" %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
```

P.S strongly recommend adding code to display MySQLi errors, because stuff happens!

Comment: Thanks for helping!